# Caracteres invalidos en metadata

Tags: android, firebase

Hola estoy intentando subir un fichero en el Storage de Firebase, el problema es que al añadirle un StorageMetadata con un campo "nombre" que contiene "Muñoz" me falla y es por que creo que contiene un caracter invalido el metadata que es la "ñ". Quisiera saber como puedo pasar esta palabra a un formato válido. Gracias

Este es el trozo de código:

```
StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
.setCustomMetadata("avatar",mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString())
.setCustomMetadata("nombre","Muñoz")
                .setContentType("image/jpg")
                .build();

        imgRef.putFile(fileUri,metadata)
```

Answer (score 1):

usa [setContentEncoding()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata.Builder.html#setContentEncoding(java.lang.String)) para definir la códificación como  UTF-8 :

```
.setContentEncoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: Hola he probado la solución que das y no me funciona, gracias por contestar

Comment: Me lanza este error:     com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation retry limit has been exceeded.

Comment: espera, eso no tiene que ver con tu problema, ese error te muestra cuando tienes .setCustomMetadata("nombre","Muñoz") ?

Comment: si es así imagino es de producción tu desarrollo, debes revisar los limites especificados : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: A ver la app se queda un buen rato (unos 20') intentando subir el fichero, bloqueada, y al cabo de ese rato me salta ese error. He probado a poner por ejemplo Munoz (sin la ñ ) y va perfectamente

Comment: Esto me aparece repetidas veces en el Log:            W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-1031372115432573568.appspot.com/o
                                                                       java.net.ProtocolException: exceeded content-length limit of 186 bytes
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RetryableSink.write(RetryableSink.java:58 ) at --------- beginning of system
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping